# JSON - invalid model schema specified for specific schema

Tags: json

I've made a model that I have troubles saving in API Gateway.
If anyone could point me to a place in the code where I've made issue I will be very grateful.

The point is that I've tried to build an array there which seem like to not be build correctly. I was using several docs to perform it but I'm failing.

Thanks in advance and best regards.

```html
{
 "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
 "title": "GetUser",
 "type": "object",
 "properties": {
  "user_id": {
   "type": "number"
  },
  "shop_id": {
   "type": "number"
  },
  "email": {
   "type": "string"
  },
  "first_name": {
   "type": "string"
  },
  "last_name": {
   "type": "string"
  },
  "gender_title": {
   "type": "string"
  },
  "language": {
   "type": "string"
  }
 },
 "birthday": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
    "day": {
     "type": "number"
    },
    "month": {
     "type": "string"
    },
    "year": {
     "type": "number"
    },

    "loyality_club_points": {
     "type": "number"
    },
    "levels_points": {
     "type": "array",
     "items": {
      "points": {
       "type": "number"
      },
      "order_tax": {
       "type": "number"
      }

     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of how you want the JSON data to look so it can be checked against the schema.  If you do try using on https://jsonschema.net to see what schema is generated and compare it.

Answer (score 0):

What I want to have is:

```
{
"user_id":          ,(number)
"shop_id":          ,(number)
"email":            ,(string)
"first_name":       ,(string)
"last_name":        ,(string)
"gender_title":     ,(string)
"language":         ,(string)
"birthday":         
    {
       "day":      ,(number)
       "month":    ,(string)
       "year":      (number)
    },
"loyalty_club_points":      ,(number)
"levels_points": 
[
    { 
       "points": 150,
       "order_tax": 3
    },
   { 
       "points": 250,
       "order_tax": 6
    },
   { 
       "points": 350,
       "order_tax": 9
    },
   { 
       "points": 550,
       "order_tax": 12
    },
   { 
      "points": 1000,
      "order_tax": 32
   }
```

]
}